# Comparison of JMeter vs Visual Studio Load Test

Tags: performance, load-testing, jmeter, visualstudio

My organization is currently planning to test the load capability of our web application (we live in a third-world country, of which testing practice is a very new thing here). In accommodating this needs, we are considering two tools : JMeter and Visual Studio.

What are the **advantages and disadvantages** of each tools?
If we are planning this as long term plan for our organization in the future, Which one is more difficult to use? Which one has more complete report?

I have tried to search in Google, but the information is always one sided.

Thanks a lot

Comment: There are other options. I'm very fond of [Gatling](http://gatling.io/#/) - it's free, more customisable than Jmeter, and good for web applications. Plus it's essentially a Scala DSL, and Scala is a pretty great language.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend JMeter as:

1. Price

   - JMeter: free and open source
   - MSVS: Test Professional costs around $2000 per developer.
2. OS supported

   - JMeter: any
   - MSVS: Windows only
3. Protocols supported

   - JMeter: HTTP, FTP, JDBC, SOAP, TCP, JMS, SMTP, POP3, IMSP
   - MSVS: HTTP

However if your company has Microsoft products based development infrastructure, like Team Foundation Server, configured continuous integration and build systems, etc. MSVS could be more reasonable choice, besides MSVS has better bundled reporting than JMeter. In any case I would recommend to take a look at [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](http://blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) post which may be helpful.

Comment: I've used MSVS load testing a bit just playing around with it, and the nicest thing I've found with it is the ability for load tests to profile your code while it's load testing it.  In other words, it'll find the problem code while under stress.  Is this something JMeter can do somehow as well?  Since JMeter is Java-based, I'm not sure how this interaction would work.

Comment: Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but MSVS's load tests can consist of any combination of MS tests.  That means you can create load tests of UI tests, Unit tests, or Web Performance tests.  So I'm not sure if saying that HTTP is the only protocol supported is correct.

Answer (score 0):

MSVS does not support only HTTP, I'm using it to test soap requests, and with adding web reference to my WebService in my testing project, I don't have to deal with building the SOAP request, MSVS deals with serialization and deserialization automatically. Also, with the power of a real programming language, you can test what ever you like, for example DB.